# Not able to compare string in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here is my logic in a code snippet.

I am trying to login, if data comes from web-page and if it matches with the database to proceed allowing to login

```
[HttpPost]//post method
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection collection)//using formcollection
{

    var logindata = amcs.Logins.Where(a => a.Admin_Email_Id == collection["Admin_Email_Id"] && a.Admin_Password == collection["Admin_Password"]).SingleOrDefault();//compare string
    if (logindata == null)//match data
    {             
        return Redirect("/Contract/Login/index");//redirect if not match
    }
    else
    {
        Session["Emailids"] = collection["EmailId"];//add session 
        Session["Passwords"] = collection["AdminPassword"];
        return Redirect("/Contract/Homepage/index");
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: Don't store credentials in Session and definitely don't store passwords in plain text

Comment: What's the problem, or error, you're getting?

Comment: I am get null value in result

Comment: i used datacontext but logindata is received null value

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting `NULL` as a result, have you looked further into this yourself?

For example, what values are

- collection["Admin_Email_Id"]
- collection["Admin_Password"]

Does the data in `amcs.Logins` contain objects whose properties match those values? You can hover the mouse of the data and look at it in the debugger.

EDIT
In response to a comment:

In the HTML does the

`<input type="text" id="Admin_Email_Id">` also have an attribute `name="Admin_Email_Id"`? If not then add it manually e.g.

`Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Admin_Email_Id, new { name = "Admin_Email_Id", PlaceHolder = "EmailId"})`

I'd be surprised that you need to do that though, but it's worth checking the HTML to check that `name` is there. Without `name`, when posting to the controller, the FormColleciton won't have a value for that missing `name`

Comment: If `amcs.Logins` didn't have one of those properties it wouldn't compile. If more than one result was returned then `SingleOrDefault()` would throw an exception. So we know that neither of those is the case.

Comment: "If amcs.Logins didn't have one of those properties it wouldn't compile." I don't believe I said that. I said if none of the objects in the collection had `Admin_Email_Id` or `Admin_Password` values that match the incoming form data, then `NULL` will be returned. I'll remove the bit about `SingleOrDefault()`, you're right it would raise an exception.

Comment: logins have property i think error in query .in same table insert query work properly .

Comment: i am not getting value from collection my code is.<%Html.BeginForm("Index", "Login", FormMethod.Post);  %>   <fieldset>
            <%:Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Admin_Email_Id, new {PlaceHolder = "EmailId"}) %>